# Is it possible to get speed limit data using OSMBonusPack?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, overpass-api

I've been trying to develop speed limit application & have tried many different approaches to get done .

I have used Overpass APIs & it did good but it did not have speed limit information for few of locations around Europe & also installed Velociraptor which uses OSM map & HERE Maps APIs still they failed to get data . Here is screenshot of Velociraptor app : [Screenshot Image](https://agora-file-storage-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/workplace/attachment/549071984425185948?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22S70405-112135.jpg%22%3B%20filename%2A%3Dutf-8%27%27S70405-112135.jpg&x-amz-security-token=FQoDYXdzECMaDGA1j1Vdp6%2FxdRvUTSK3A%2FO3q%2FgJ4%2Fuw9nfzztOBKStLOjmxftllrc3qG9n35fBdhNtnRAJ6VuduSGRxHrXmKrlWlS%2FpAHfHFr1t6Hv3Hs6WuLFm%2BRXU2UEH85tDSv6J%2BTSqNBWwEQZzvTNVwd4yDsfUtwskOo1L5VrcGuoScIkIHGpeJPCeiVHuu97AZKc3gZ5ts51wz9HxlNixLtwE0IVIyoqWCUU8QSM%2B0l7P3vESEbKcyf4uk5aAXGV14EyYlyBfxUxHpipg6%2FuEIjKOFw5Y8hf3hZzw2wO9xB8TT8hFnXs0UwJAa4p1WCROc24oeUWqaOBZNv%2B%2BbDlO%2BaOi9nJDpbpOFdXwrg4vWPiaRPopUCmSSdTiRJE9C4pXwtm71%2BaGFwEHBLWDr7USG9pWyPtur4HsZK3JySx4EQOUxBJZYxXuZKdMULwaSYqqKRePX%2Bt%2BDAqP5bzU88bxnFQD23kB01ctsVCCakoDzlySjmURCmcnXK5Y5R0cYC%2BYsg1qMQ81%2B8wM8PBwPpZKe%2BvU%2Bfq3Hdr%2B%2BgoMIaS0pZCniHQyLAAMv9mhfvNT%2BXaCiB2ArDa2UYQJ%2B%2FpTTIfc21HjytZLiEUwdE0oke6bxwU%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAI7ICHY2QTN7QRLCQ&Expires=1491535506&Signature=p6XeWu%2BNtPIr7kKayndhTGox8E0%3D) .

Yesterday I came across osmbonuspack & it looks promising as it allows us to choose from 3 best routing services available . So , before I proceed with implementation I thought it might be useful to get suggestions on if we can get speed limit from this project.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the 3 routing services are not returning speed limit information. 
Options:

contact them directly to convince them to add speed limit per segment

fork an open source one (OSRM?), and implement yourself

back to OverpassAPI or Velociraptor

Comment: Okay , Thanks for your suggestion.