# Can we get Speed limit information from Waze APIs?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, overpass-api

I've been trying to develop speed limit application & have tried many different approaches to get done .

I have used Overpass APIs & it did good but it did not have speed limit information for few of locations around Europe & also installed Velociraptor which uses OSM map & HERE Maps APIs still they failed to get data . Here is screenshot of Velociraptor app :

[image]

Yesterday I came across osmbonuspack & it looks promising as it allows us to choose from 3 best routing services available but Author of osmbonuspack told me that unfortunately, the 3 routing services are not returning speed limit information. Refer : [Is it possible to get speed limit data using OSMBonusPack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269086/is-it-possible-to-get-speed-limit-data-using-osmbonuspack)

I have installed Waze application & it has speed limit data for locations around Europe which are not available from above options. So , anyone has a idea how they are getting information OR anyone knows which datasource they are using ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please upload screenshots directly at StackOverflow. Your Link has already expired.

Comment: are you sure that Waze has public API?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Nope, waze doesn't have public APIs , only Waze Map Apis are public AFAIK & they are providing SDK for android platform which open Waze client from our app.

Comment: I don;t think that opening their app from your app can be called an API. Please provide at least a link to their API and Documentation

Comment: see edited comment. Also updated my question.

Comment: Hey any luck with your speed limit app? I'm making the same thing but haven't figured out how to put speed limits on google map since google map api doesn't have speed limit data unless you pay for premium subscription and use road api

Comment: @Ralph , I've not developed it later but found out that you have to use OpenStreetMap if you need speed limit data for free . You can find out more about here : https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/54894/best-way-to-retrieve-speed-limit-of-road . Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid Waze does not use another data source or at the very least not one unique data source that you could use. As a crowd-sourced application it relies on the information entered by map editors via the [Waze Map Editor](https://www.waze.com/editor/). Some editors might have used some open data sources available for their regions (if permitted by their local organisation), but it's far more likely they've used their local knowledge, Google Street View (Waze has a special license for that) or user reports sent in via the app.

As the map used by Waze is not open data, I'd highly advice against attempting to retrieve the speed data from their map. They have not exposed this information in an open API, which should be a strong indication that reuse of this data is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

OSM tagging is rich and flexible, but can be quite difficult to interpret. 
Typically, max speed information is certainly there (the various routing services are based on it). The point is: how it's defined?

Have a close look here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing/Maxspeed

And you will discover that getting maxspeed tag is not enough...

Then, refining your Overpass queries, maybe you will be able to get it everywhere!

Other hint: look at OSRM source code (or ask them), to see how they get this information.